# Executing multiple commands while in a Goroutine fails after some number of iterations?

Tags: go

I have some long running goroutines that exec shell commands. This fails after an arbitrary number of commands have been run (288 times on my Linux box for this example, and 400 for my Mac). If I run the exact same code outside a goroutine, it continues as expected without stopping or errors. I've tried debugging by setting breakpoints, but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Does not work:

```
func main() {
    go doAlot()
    for {
    }
}

func doAlot() {
    i := 0
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)
        cmd := exec.Command("echo", "hello")
        var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
        cmd.Stdout = &stdout
        cmd.Stderr = &stderr
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
        }
        outStr, errStr := string(stdout.Bytes()), string(stderr.Bytes())
        fmt.Printf("%d \nout: %serr: %s\n", i, outStr, errStr)
        i++
    }
}
```

Works:

```
func main() {
    i := 0
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)
        cmd := exec.Command("echo", "hello")
        var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
        cmd.Stdout = &stdout
        cmd.Stderr = &stderr
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
        }
        outStr, errStr := string(stdout.Bytes()), string(stderr.Bytes())
        fmt.Printf("%d\nout: %serr: %s\n", i, outStr, errStr)
        i++
    }
}
```

My only (uneducated/wild) guess, is that it relates to garbage collection and buffers, but somehow connected specifically to running inside a goroutine.

Comment: What error did you capture?

Comment: Can you try `select{ }` instead of infinite loop?

Comment: I don't see any problem. Working fine for me. Somethings else is responsible. Can you run this code https://play.golang.org/p/IMCGpxoO0UH ?

Comment: A busy loop is always a mistake. Eventually it’s going to block the scheduler

Comment: Thank you @JimB. It works now by removing the busy loop. Using select{} instead there is no error. I have started reading up on the Go scheduler more.

Comment: @aerokite Yes, select{} works. I've just learned it is wrong to call an empty busy loop in Go, so that was my issue. Appreciate the help.